# How to spawn a detached process on Darwin?

Tags: macos, go

How to spawn a detached process on macOS?
When I try to do it using `exec.Command` and set proper `SysProcAttr`, I get:

```
Error during starting process X: fork/exec X: operation not permitted
```

I found that it's due to Go concurrency model. Is there another way to do it?

Edit:
@suggested two answers: Spawned process has necessary permissions and can be run from cmd line. Also suggested answers don't spawn a detached process.

Below MRE: it spawns a process, that has is not fully detached, and when killed by 9 signal leaves a zombie process. When you uncomment any of commented sysattr entries, you should get error I mentioned.

```
package main

import (
   "fmt"
   "log"
   "os/exec"
   "syscall"
)

func main() {
   cmd :=exec.Command("./testBinary")
   cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
      //Setsid: true,
      Setpgid: true,
      //Pgid: 1,
   }
   cmd.Stdin = nil
   cmd.Stdout = nil
   cmd.Stderr = nil

   if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
      log.Printf("Error during spawning process:\n%s\n", err)
   }
   log.Printf("Spawned a process with pid %d\n", cmd.Process.Pid)
   fmt.Scanln()
}
```

Comment: Please share an MRE: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65408545/1507669 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/58976194/1507669

Comment: exec would execute a subcommand, with the correct sys-attributes you could potentially fork it. the text "operation not permitted" could also mean that your user is not permitted to execute whatever subcommand you intended to? Have you checked your user and access rights on whatever command you intend to start?